# "Видишь" в данном случае вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

*Вот как надо! Видишь, твоя подруга уже почти закончила.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Видишь (ли)** относится к вводным словам, представляющим собой призыв к собеседнику или к читателю с целью привлечь его внимание к сообщаемому, внушить определенное отношение к излагаемым мыслям, к приводимым фактам.
[Вводные слова и сочетания](http://lingvotech.com/vvod)

В зависимости от контекста одни и те же слова выступают то в качестве членов предложения, то в роли вводных слов (следовательно, не членов предложения).
Если слово можно изъять из состава предложения, то оно вводное (структура предложения при этом сохраняется), если же нельзя — это член предложения.

1. **Вот как надо! Видишь, твоя подруга уже почти закончила.**
   Думаю, что "видишь" в этом предложении является вводным словом (смысл предложения при его "изничтожении" не меняется). Диалог может происходить в любом месте — обращается внимание на сам факт.
2. [Ты] ***Видишь, что*** твоя подруга уже почти закончила?
   При такой структуре предложения мы имеем СПП, в котором "видишь" является сказуемым. Диалог происходит в том месте, где находится подруга и "её дело", которое она закончила. Внимание сосредоточено на производимом действии.